What will happen to Voyager if it just orbits the galaxy forever?
Will it be torn apart by cosmic ray protons? Micrometeors?
Nothing?
Will it silently watch Andromeda approach and pass through us?
Will the golden record still be playable 10 billion years from now, long after the sun goes out?

Space is big. I doubt it’d ever hit anything. I don’t know if metal can physically withstand neutrons for extended periods of time, though. The Golden Record, if not hit by anything or ground into dust by radiation and wind, would still be playable; it’s intended to last for billions of years if I’m not mistaken. That’s all I know.

@controlgroup "I don’t know if metal can physically withstand neutrons for extended periods of time" == By an amazing coincidence, I once spent a year designing a gizmo to predict time until unacceptable neutron damage to the stainless steel crystal lattice of reactor shielding. Unfortunately, all my amazing coincidences are worthless. I never win the lottery.

Isn't it going to merge with some alien craft and then come looking for Earth?

That's awesome actually. I would trust you over myself on the topic of radiology in that case (I deal more with relativity and more fundamental physics than the engineering of such things).

different but related: For how long will the Voyager records remain playable? (only guesses for answers)

@OrganicMarble That was Voyager 6.

It has been calculated that it will take 10^20 years before Voyager collides with something. Unless there's something were missing, this is the only thing that is likely to eventually destroy the Voyagers.

Will the golden record still be playable 10 billion years from now, long after the sun goes out?

The records were designed to survive for at least 1 billion years, so possibly. After all, the probes will be unlikely to have suferred any damage.

Wouldn't sputtering by interstellar dust or gas also be a factor that would lead to more gradual erosion?

I think that's considered a collision (as ultimately the dust/gas does hit the spacecraft, otherwise there's not really a problem).@ikrase
